# sqlite query return not null

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm studying android-develop myself. Here is:

```
Cursor cursor=mSQLiteDatabase.query(...);  
if(cursor==null)return null;  
cursor.moveToFirst();  
return cursor;
```

The question is: When the query result is empty,but the cursor return is not null. So the `cursor.moveToFirst()` caught exception.

How?

Comment: try if(!cursor.moveToFirst()) return null;

Comment: @Vic if the questions is solved, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3):

Even for queries that do not have results,I believe a non-null cursor is still returned. You have to call `Cursor.getCount()` to make sure its not zero.